# difference-redirecting to bit bucket(aka /dev/null) vs closing the file descriptor

Tags: bash, shell, unix, scripting, ksh

Is there any difference between the below two commands?

```
ls -l some_non_existing_file 2>/dev/null
```

and

```
ls -l some_non_existing_file 2>&-
```

Both seems to work but I have seen only the first one being used practically so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Attempts by the program to output data to stderr will fail in the second case with `EBADF`. Whether the program cares or not is a separate issue.

Comment: :Could you please provide an example?. I tried, "ls -l some_existing_file 2>&- 1>&2" but it seemed to work fine.

Comment: @toddlermenot: Read the second sentence again.